# Strapi - How to GET data sorted based on relation property?

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I have an Articles table and it has a relation with the Authors table. Each author has a name property. I want to make a GET request for the articles and receive the articles sorted based on their author's name.

When I use `_sort=author` in the url parameters, I get the articles sorted based on the author object's ID.

When I use `_sort=author.name` in the url parameters, I get the articles in a seemingly random order but definitely not based on author.name.

How can I get the data sorted based on author.name?

I use mongoDB as my database.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of `_sort`. However, you can simply accomplish this by overriding the `find` method in `api/article/services/article.js` to sort by Author's name like so:

```js
module.exports = {
    async find(params, populate) {
        let result = await strapi.query('article').find(params, populate);

        if (params._sort == 'author')
            return result.sort((a, b) => (a.author.name > b.author.name) ? 1 : -1);

        return result;
    },
}
```

Check the documentation for customizing services to get more info: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/services.html#concept

Comment: This won't work with pagination, right?